# Deep Clone objects in C#

Tags: c#, object, clone

I was playing with different techniques for deep object cloning in C#, and finally came to pretty elegant solution that uses reflection and is applicable for non-serializable types. I am just wondering is there something wrong with it, and if anybody has comments or use case that does not work with this approach. Here is the code. Thanks for comments!

```
    public static T Clone<T>(this T source)
    {
        //  Get the type 
        Type type = source.GetType();
        T clone = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        //  Loop through the properties
        foreach (PropertyInfo pInfo in type.GetProperties())
        {
            pInfo.SetValue(clone, pInfo.GetValue(source, null), null);
        }
        //  Loop through the fields
        foreach (FieldInfo fInfo in type.GetFields())
        {
            fInfo.SetValue(clone, fInfo.GetValue(source).Clone());
        }
        return clone;
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you clone a handle to an unmanaged resource? Bam! Dead. If your objects don't support deep copies -> don't do it.

Comment: You might get more comments on this type of question if you post it to code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Definitely make sure to not get into an infinite loop for objects that have children objects with parent references

Comment: voting to close; "Not a Real Question". Not a question at all, actually.

Comment: Question is: is there something wrong with this code and what, and i got some amazing answers in just 10 minutes.

Comment: This question would be better phrased 'What is the best way to do a deep clone in C#' instead of posting a single, specific example and asking for flaws.

Comment: @stefan Are you aware there is a site custom-made for questions just like this? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6):

There are several issues I can see:

1. You only copy public properties and fields
2. You don't clone the property value, you just copy it. This means it's not a deep clone on properties.
3. There are certain types which are not easily clonable (or should not be cloned at all) like streams or filehandles (or any unmanaged resource for that matter) - your method might run into trouble there.
4. Your method won't handle circular references.
5. Not all types have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: You are right, I see the flaws, but it is still useful. I was writing a bunch of unit tests that use similar objects as mock parameters. It was convenient to create these objects as globals, and use clones for individual test.

Answer (score 2):

What if there is no accessible parameterless constructor?

What if there is an member object that can't be shared (a file handle, maybe)?

What about non-public members?

Why the need to create a one-size fits all solution to a problem that doesn't exist (you don't need to be able to deep clone everything!)?

Comment: Your last qestion is valid but has an obvious answer: We are lazy. If we need a quick'n'dirty deep copy we can use this. It's much like the old "undo" hack where you copy the entire application memory and just -reload it when user hit CTRL+Z. Not everything has to follow MVC.